# Navigation without lidar

Tags: ros, navigation, ros-melodic, 2dlidar

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello.
I am new to ROS and not sure exactly where this would fall under, so please bear in that in mind..

I am working on a differential drive robots project. We are using an off the shelf positioning system based on cameras(dragonfly). It gives us x,y,z (relative to a defined origin) or WGS84 coordinates.

It creates SLAM internationally without lidar.

All of the navigation and path planning seem to operate directly off of slam created from the lidar.

Is there a module that works with just coordinates for navigation/path planning?

Thanks so much!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/344641/navigation-without-lidar/) by [jamie-h](https://answers.ros.org/users/51921/jamie-h/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2020-02-19

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Nothing in navigation strictly required a laser, or any particular sensor. It is *easier* admittedly with a lidar because you can use AMCL "for free" as a starting point for localization. If you have a localization method from other sensing, then there's no reason you cannot use the navigation stack assuming you have some sensing to avoid obstacles and some pre-built (or building while moving) environment map that can be used to plan and control in.

---

Originally posted by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) with karma: 8272 on 2020-02-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) on 2020-02-19**:
Without *some* sensor to provide information about the immediate environment though, it will be difficult to use collision avoidance local planning. But perhaps @jamie-h has some other means for that.

**Comment by [aarish_shah](https://answers.ros.org/users/136211/aarish_shah/) on 2023-02-01**:
Hi,

The navigation [wiki](http://wiki.ros.org/navigation) lists the following requirement: "It requires a planar laser mounted somewhere on the mobile base. This laser is used for map building and localization." This seems to contradict what @stevemacenski is saying.

I am using a differential-drive robot with a positioning sensor which gives me the relative coordinates of the robot in my map and a camera. I want to use the navigation stack for just path-planning, no localization. Can I do that?

**Comment by [stevemacenski](https://answers.ros.org/users/25940/stevemacenski/) on 2023-02-06**:
That is not the ROS 2 stack nor is it accurate. Anyone can edit the old ROS 1 wiki and add misunderstandings.

**Comment by [aarish_shah](https://answers.ros.org/users/136211/aarish_shah/) on 2023-02-06**:
Alright, thanks!